# The median of the absolute value of the difference of two dependent log normal random variables

Tags: simulation, density-function, median, numerical-integration, integral

Assume X and Y have a bivariate lognormal distribution (x,y>0) that is:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)$=$$\frac{1}{2p\sqrt{1-r^2}xy\sigma_1\sigma_2}exp\{\frac{-1}{2(1-r^2)}[(\frac{ln(x)-\mu_1}{\sigma_1})^2-2r(\frac{ln(x)-\mu_1}{\sigma_1})(\frac{ln(y)-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})+(\frac{ln(y)-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})^2]\}$$
I want to know the median of |x-y|.
first I calculated the density of |x-y| based on changing the variables, as follows:

I took u=|x-y| and v=y then

\begin{cases}
x=u+v,  & \text{if x>y which result in: u>0 , v>0} \\
x=v−u, & \text{if x<y which result in v>u>0}
\end{cases}
The Jacobian is one, so the density function of u=|x-y| is:
$$f_{U}(u)=\int_{0}^\infty f_{X,Y}(u+v,v)dv+\int_{u}^\infty f_{X,Y}(v-u,v)dv$$

my question is: how can I calculate the median of the above density using numerical integration(assume for the simplest case where  $\mu=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
         1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} and \sigma= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0.95 \\
        0.95 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$)?
 I am quite new in R..I really appreciate any help

Comment: If you ask a numerical question (using numerical integration), you need to provide numerical parameter values and the functional form. Also see related http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152850/difference-of-two-i-i-d-lognormal-random-variables  and your structure is more complicated via dependence.

Comment: I made some changes regarding your comment. is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Monte Carlo approach could work. This method approximates the distribution using a finite set of samples, then computes the median based on the samples. Draw $n$ independent samples of $X$ and $Y$ from the joint distribution: $\{(x_1, y_1), ... (x_n, y_n)\}$. I'll explain how do do this below. This gives samples of $U$: $\{u_1, ..., u_n\}$, where $u_i = |x_i - y_i|$. Take the median of these samples. Accuracy will increase with $n$, which you could easily set in the thousands or millions.

Your problem has special structure that makes it possible to sample $X$ and $Y$ directly from the joint distribution. $\log X$ and $\log Y$ have a bivariate normal distribution from which you can easily sample using a multivariate Gaussian random number generator (using the appropriate mean and covariance matrix). This [blog post](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/08/simulating-form-the-bivariate-normal-distribution-in-r-1.html) describes how to do this in R. Once you have samples of $\log X$ and $\log Y$, exponentiate these values to obtain samples of $X$ and $Y$. It's not always possible to sample directly from a given distribution, in which case methods like [MCMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) algorithms can be used. Luckily, this isn't necessary in your case.

Comment: Thank you, I am a little confused. how can I get the $u_i$ samples from MCMC algorithm? Would you mind providing some codes?

Comment: There's actually an easy way to do sample directly. See my edited answer.